# what is and how does href= ?id works

Tags: php, html, href

So I learned today how to make a pagination.
When I echo my table data it works nicely.
When I click in a page number link to change to other page of results, it add to the URL .../testPag.php **?id=58**.
What I don't understand is what is the purpose of the "?" on the href.
so what is the idea behind "?" on the href of a link and what is it called so I can learn more about it :)

the code is `<a href="testPag.php?id='.$id.'">`

the $id is the id of rows in my table's database.

Comment: This is basic HTML stuff - the GET protocol. Please read about this stuff here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: GET is not a protocol, it's a method of the HTTP protocol

Comment: Look up $_GET superglobal for php

Comment: There wasn't much research done on this.

Answer (score 0):

Anything after `?` in a URL denotes HTTP GET parameters, this way you can pass dynamic data to the web-server, in your case the ID of something (page?).